# Login Form > Overlay Closes on Form Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm wrestling with an issue involving a log in form which is fetched using Ajax then displayed in a jQuery overlay. The overlay works perfectly, the issue is that when I click `submit` (using incorrect details) a the overlay closes instead of displaying the appropriate errors. The PHP code is on the login page (admin/index.php).

Button HTML:

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Log In" class="submit" />
```

Form tag HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="">
```

PHP code:

```
ob_start();
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include '../includes/config.php';
session_name('cmsLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['cmsRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe']) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}

if($_SESSION['id'] && isset($_COOKIE['cmsRemember'])) {
    header("Location: loggedIn.php");
}

if($_POST['formName']=='login') {
    $err = array();

    if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = '<strong>Error:</strong> Please ensure the email &amp; password fields have been completed.';

    if(!count($err)) {
        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_members WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['email']) {
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];     
            setcookie('cmsRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='<strong>Error:</strong> The email and/or password you have entered is invalid.';
    }

    if($err) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("Location: loggedIn.php");
    }
}
else {
}

$script = '';
```

Javascript:

```
(function($){

    //closeDOMWindow
    $.fn.closeDOMWindow = function(settings){

        if(!settings){settings={};}

        var run = function(passingThis){

            if(settings.anchoredClassName){
                var $anchorClassName = $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName);
                $anchorClassName.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    if($.fn.draggable){
                        $anchorClassName.draggable('destory').trigger("unload").remove();   
                    }else{
                        $anchorClassName.trigger("unload").remove();
                    }
                });
                if(settings.functionCallOnClose){settings.functionCallAfterClose();}
            }else{
                var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
                var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
                $DOMWindowOverlay.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $DOMWindowOverlay.trigger('unload').unbind().remove();                                                                    
                });
                $DOMWindow.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    if($.fn.draggable){
                        $DOMWindow.draggable("destroy").trigger("unload").remove();
                    }else{
                        $DOMWindow.trigger("unload").remove();
                    }
                });

                $(window).unbind('scroll.DOMWindow');
                $(window).unbind('resize.DOMWindow');

                if($.fn.openDOMWindow.isIE6){$('#DOMWindowIE6FixIframe').remove();}
                if(settings.functionCallOnClose){settings.functionCallAfterClose();}
            }   
        };

        if(settings.eventType){//if used with $().
            return this.each(function(index){
                $(this).bind(settings.eventType, function(){
                    run(this);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }else{//else called as $.function
            run();
        }

    };

    //allow for public call, pass settings
    $.closeDOMWindow = function(s){$.fn.closeDOMWindow(s);};

    //openDOMWindow
    $.fn.openDOMWindow = function(instanceSettings){    

        var shortcut =  $.fn.openDOMWindow;

        //default settings combined with callerSettings////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        shortcut.defaultsSettings = {
            anchoredClassName:'',
            anchoredSelector:'',
            borderColor:'#FFFFFF',
            borderSize:'0',
            draggable:0,
            eventType:'click', //click, blur, change, dblclick, error, focus, load, mousedown, mouseout, mouseup etc...
            fixedWindowY:20,
            functionCallOnOpen:null,
            functionCallOnClose:null,
            height:340,
            loader:1,
            loaderHeight:32,
            loaderImagePath:'images/icon_loader.gif',
            loaderWidth:32,
            modal:0,
            overlay:1,
            overlayColor:'#000',
            overlayOpacity:'75',
            positionLeft:0,
            positionTop:10,
            positionType:'centered', // centered, anchored, absolute, fixed
            width:280,
            windowBGColor:'',
            windowBGImage:null, // http path
            windowHTTPType:'get',
            windowPadding:0,
            windowSource:'ajax', //inline, ajax, iframe
            windowSourceID:'',
            windowSourceURL:'',
            windowSourceAttrURL:'href'
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.openDOMWindow.defaultsSettings , instanceSettings || {});

        //Public functions

        shortcut.viewPortHeight = function(){ return self.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;};
        shortcut.viewPortWidth = function(){ return self.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;};
        shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight = function(){ return self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;};
        shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth = function(){ return self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;};
        shortcut.isIE6 = typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined";

        //Private Functions/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var sizeOverlay = function(){
            var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
            if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                var overlayViewportHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop - 4;
                var overlayViewportWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - 21;
                $DOMWindowOverlay.css({'height':overlayViewportHeight +'px','width':overlayViewportWidth+'px'});
            }else{//else Firefox, safari, opera, IE 7+
                $DOMWindowOverlay.css({'height':'100%','width':'100%','position':'fixed'});
            }   
        };

        var sizeIE6Iframe = function(){
            var overlayViewportHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop - 4;
            var overlayViewportWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - 21;
            $('#DOMWindowIE6FixIframe').css({'height':overlayViewportHeight +'px','width':overlayViewportWidth+'px'});
        };

        var centerDOMWindow = function() {
            var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
            if(settings.height + 50 > shortcut.viewPortHeight()){//added 50 to be safe
                $DOMWindow.css('left',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerWidth())/2));
            }else{
                $DOMWindow.css('left',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerWidth())/2));
                $DOMWindow.css('top',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortHeight()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerHeight())/2));
            }
        };

        var centerLoader = function() {
            var $DOMWindowLoader = $('#DOMWindowLoader');
            if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'left':Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindowLoader.innerWidth())/2),'position':'absolute'});
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'top':Math.round(shortcut.viewPortHeight()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight() - Math.round(($DOMWindowLoader.innerHeight())/2),'position':'absolute'});
            }else{
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'left':'50%','top':'50%','position':'fixed'});
            }

        };

        var fixedDOMWindow = function(){
            var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
            $DOMWindow.css('left', settings.positionLeft + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth());
            $DOMWindow.css('top', + settings.positionTop + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight());
        };

        var showDOMWindow = function(instance){
            if(arguments[0]){
                $('.'+instance+' #DOMWindowLoader').remove();
                $('.'+instance+' #DOMWindowContent').fadeIn('fast',function(){if(settings.functionCallOnOpen){settings.functionCallOnOpen();}});
                $('.'+instance+ '.closeDOMWindow').click(function(){
                    $.closeDOMWindow(); 
                    return false;
                });
            }else{
                $('#DOMWindowLoader').remove();
                $('#DOMWindow').fadeIn('fast',function(){if(settings.functionCallOnOpen){settings.functionCallOnOpen();}});
                $('#DOMWindow .closeDOMWindow').click(function(){                       
                    $.closeDOMWindow();
                    return false;
                });
            }

        };

        var urlQueryToObject = function(s){
              var query = {};
              s.replace(/b([^&=]*)=([^&=]*)b/g, function (m, a, d) {
                if (typeof query[a] != 'undefined') {
                  query[a] += ',' + d;
                } else {
                  query[a] = d;
                }
              });
              return query;
        };

        //Run Routine ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var run = function(passingThis){

            //get values from element clicked, or assume its passed as an option
            settings.windowSourceID = $(passingThis).attr('href') || settings.windowSourceID;
            settings.windowSourceURL = $(passingThis).attr(settings.windowSourceAttrURL) || settings.windowSourceURL;
            settings.windowBGImage = settings.windowBGImage ? 'background-image:url('+settings.windowBGImage+')' : '';
            var urlOnly, urlQueryObject;

            if(settings.positionType == 'anchored'){//anchored DOM window

                var anchoredPositions = $(settings.anchoredSelector).position();
                var anchoredPositionX = anchoredPositions.left + settings.positionLeft;
                var anchoredPositionY = anchoredPositions.top + settings.positionTop;

                $('body').append('<div class="'+settings.anchoredClassName+'" style="'+settings.windowBGImage+';background-repeat:no-repeat;padding:'+settings.windowPadding+'px;overflow:auto;position:absolute;top:'+anchoredPositionY+'px;left:'+anchoredPositionX+'px;height:'+settings.height+'px;width:'+settings.width+'px;background-color:'+settings.windowBGColor+';border:'+settings.borderSize+'px solid '+settings.borderColor+';z-index:10001"><div id="DOMWindowContent" style="display:none"></div></div>');        
                //loader
                if(settings.loader && settings.loaderImagePath !== ''){
                    $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName).append('<div id="DOMWindowLoader" style="width:'+settings.loaderWidth+'px;height:'+settings.loaderHeight+'px;"><img src="'+settings.loaderImagePath+'" /></div>');

                }

                if($.fn.draggable){
                    if(settings.draggable){$('.' + settings.anchoredClassName).draggable({cursor:'move'});}
                }

                switch(settings.windowSource){
                    case 'inline'://////////////////////////////// inline //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").append($(settings.windowSourceID).children());
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName).unload(function(){// move elements back when you're finished
                            $('.' + settings.windowSourceID).append( $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").children());              
                        });
                        showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                    break;
                    case 'iframe'://////////////////////////////// iframe //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").append('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" wspace="0" src="'+settings.windowSourceURL+'" name="DOMWindowIframe'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000)+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;background-color:#fff;" class="'+settings.anchoredClassName+'Iframe" ></iframe>');
                        $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName+'Iframe').load(showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName));
                    break;
                    case 'ajax'://////////////////////////////// ajax //////////////////////////////////////////    
                        if(settings.windowHTTPType == 'post'){

                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1){//has a query string
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL.substr(0, settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?"));
                                urlQueryObject = urlQueryToObject(settings.windowSourceURL);
                            }else{
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL;
                                urlQueryObject = {};
                            }
                            $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").load(urlOnly,urlQueryObject,function(){
                                showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                            });
                        }else{
                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") == -1){ //no query string, so add one
                                settings.windowSourceURL += '?';
                            }
                            $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").load(
                                settings.windowSourceURL + '&random=' + (new Date().getTime()),function(){
                                showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                            });
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }else{//centered, fixed, absolute DOM window

                //overlay & modal
                if(settings.overlay){
                    $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindowOverlay" style="z-index:10000;display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:'+settings.overlayColor+';filter:alpha(opacity='+settings.overlayOpacity+');-moz-opacity: 0.'+settings.overlayOpacity+';opacity: 0.'+settings.overlayOpacity+';"></div>');
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                        $('body').append('<iframe id="DOMWindowIE6FixIframe"  src="blank.html"  style="width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);"></iframe>');
                        sizeIE6Iframe();
                    }
                    sizeOverlay();
                    var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
                    $DOMWindowOverlay.fadeIn('fast');
                    if(!settings.modal){$DOMWindowOverlay.click(function(){$.closeDOMWindow();});}
                }

                //loader
                if(settings.loader && settings.loaderImagePath !== ''){
                    $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindowLoader" style="z-index:10002;width:'+settings.loaderWidth+'px;height:'+settings.loaderHeight+'px;"><img src="'+settings.loaderImagePath+'" /></div>');
                    centerLoader();
                }

                //add DOMwindow
                $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindow" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;'+settings.windowBGImage+';overflow:auto;padding:'+settings.windowPadding+'px;display:none;height:'+settings.height+'px;width:'+settings.width+'px;background-color:'+settings.windowBGColor+';border:'+settings.borderSize+'px solid '+settings.borderColor+'; position:absolute;z-index:10001"></div>');

                var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
                //centered, absolute, or fixed
                switch(settings.positionType){
                    case 'centered':
                        centerDOMWindow();
                        if(settings.height + 50 > shortcut.viewPortHeight()){//added 50 to be safe
                            $DOMWindow.css('top', (settings.fixedWindowY + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight()) + 'px');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'absolute':
                        $DOMWindow.css({'top':(settings.positionTop+shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight())+'px','left':(settings.positionLeft+shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth())+'px'});
                        if($.fn.draggable){
                            if(settings.draggable){$DOMWindow.draggable({cursor:'move'});}
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'fixed':
                        fixedDOMWindow();
                    break;
                    case 'anchoredSingleWindow':
                        var anchoredPositions = $(settings.anchoredSelector).position();
                        var anchoredPositionX = anchoredPositions.left + settings.positionLeft;
                        var anchoredPositionY = anchoredPositions.top + settings.positionTop;
                        $DOMWindow.css({'top':anchoredPositionY + 'px','left':anchoredPositionX+'px'});

                    break;
                }

                $(window).bind('scroll.DOMWindow',function(){
                    if(settings.overlay){sizeOverlay();}
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){sizeIE6Iframe();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'centered'){centerDOMWindow();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'fixed'){fixedDOMWindow();}
                });

                $(window).bind('resize.DOMWindow',function(){
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){sizeIE6Iframe();}
                    if(settings.overlay){sizeOverlay();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'centered'){centerDOMWindow();}
                });

                switch(settings.windowSource){
                    case 'inline'://////////////////////////////// inline //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $DOMWindow.append($(settings.windowSourceID).children());
                        $DOMWindow.unload(function(){// move elements back when you're finished
                            $(settings.windowSourceID).append($DOMWindow.children());               
                        });
                        showDOMWindow();
                    break;
                    case 'iframe'://////////////////////////////// iframe //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $DOMWindow.append('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" wspace="0" src="'+settings.windowSourceURL+'" name="DOMWindowIframe'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000)+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;background-color:#fff;" id="DOMWindowIframe" ></iframe>');
                        $('#DOMWindowIframe').load(showDOMWindow());
                    break;
                    case 'ajax'://////////////////////////////// ajax //////////////////////////////////////////
                        if(settings.windowHTTPType == 'post'){

                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1){//has a query string
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL.substr(0, settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?"));
                                urlQueryObject = urlQueryToObject(settings.windowSourceURL);
                            }else{
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL;
                                urlQueryObject = {};
                            }
                            $DOMWindow.load(urlOnly,urlQueryObject,function(){
                                showDOMWindow();
                            });
                        }else{
                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") == -1){ //no query string, so add one
                                settings.windowSourceURL += '?';
                            }
                            $DOMWindow.load(
                                settings.windowSourceURL + '&random=' + (new Date().getTime()),function(){
                                showDOMWindow();
                            });
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }//end if anchored, or absolute, fixed, centered

        };//end run()

        if(settings.eventType){//if used with $().
            return this.each(function(index){                 
                $(this).bind(settings.eventType,function(){
                    run(this);
                    return false;
                });
            }); 
        }else{//else called as $.function
            run();
        }

    };//end function openDOMWindow

    //allow for public call, pass settings
    $.openDOMWindow = function(s){$.fn.openDOMWindow(s);};

})(jQuery);
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appresiated.

Thanks,
@rrfive

Comment: The actual javascript that creates the overlay would be helpful. I don't see how this is related to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Reason that your modal closes is that when you click submit your running your backend code, this being PHP and with your PHP you are redirecting the user if the result is negative, you need to capture the response from your PHP rather than having your PHP do a redirect.

What you can do is make your submit an ajax submit and set the data response to json, then you can write  a json response that your jquery can understand, this way all the validation will be done on the backend in the background without needed to redirect.